# Outer Div will not stretch to fit inner div (using clear)

Tags: css, html, outer-join, stretched

I've been reading about how elements with the `float` attribute do not have their height accounted for. Therefore, I should use `clear:both` right before the end of the parent div so that it will stretch over the entire inner div.

You can see on [This Page](http://blacktiephotographers.com/about-us/) that the div with the id `full-height-template-container` is not stretching over its inner content, and therefore the footer (copyright text on the bottom right) is coming up too high on the page.

The layout looks like this:

```
<div id="full-height-template-containter">
  <div id="content-container">
    <div id="full-width" style="float:left;"> 
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

What else can I try in order to make the outer div stretch over its children?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try putting content in the clearfix div's (even if it's just a space).

Comment: I tried this also, it didn't work for me.

Comment: why are you using ids instead of classes? a page should never have 2 elements with the same id

Comment: Where do you see identical ID's - might just be an error.

Comment: It is probably because you are using `height: 100%` which means the div takes 100% height of the parent. If we track back in your CSS you can see that the height is taken from the window - so the div will never exceed the size of the window. So it is not the clearing of the floats that are the problem, it is the height you are explicitly assigning to each div.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts You were right! That allowed it to stretch! Make that an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: @Evan sorry for the late response. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `#full-height-template-container` you are using `height: 100%` which means the div takes 100% height of the parent.

If we track back in your CSS each parent element is assigned `height: 100%`, including the `html` and `body` elements, which means that the height is taken from the window - so as a result the div will never exceed the size of the window (but content will still overflow).

So it is not the floats that are causing the problem, it is the height you are explicitly assigning to each div.

Answer (score 2):

That's a common problem. To solve it, the [clearfix hack](http://perishablepress.com/new-clearfix-hack/) in its many variants was invented.

Comment: I implemented this, but still having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was confronting the same issue until I inserted this version of "Clearfix" at the top of the container that needs to be stretched as such:

CSS:

```
.clearfix:after {content: "."; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility:hidden;}
.clearfix {display: inline-block;}
/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clearfix {height: 1%;}
.clearfix {display: block;}
/* End hide from IE-mac */
```

HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix"> </div>

<span class="doc">
     <a href="../speakers/johnnixon.html" "class="spkrs1">John Nixon</a> 
     <a href="../speakers/pricereveil.html" "class="spkrs2">Henry Wright</a> 
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

i put your sample on fiddle and gave it some css to show the divs:
http://jsfiddle.net/WRzsE/

You can clearly see that it works perfectly as you describe you would expect it to. You are doing something else wrong i suspect...

Perhaps you are using a `position: absolute` somewhere, wich would cause the elemnt to be lifted out of its parent, and would make the parent not stretch (just thinking out loud here...)

**edit:**
I just took a look at the actual page (overlooked the link). Your div's are stretching just fine. The problem is with the positioning of your footer, wich is set to absolute. I suspect you are trying to achieve a sticky footer, have a look at this, works like a charm. I use it all the time: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/